# Neovim syntax coloring stops working

Tags: neovim

I'm on a vanilla Debian 12 system using Neovim 0.9.4 in a tmux (3.3a) session with `TERM` as `screen-256color`  My (n)vim plugins are `nerdtree`, `vim-airline`, `vim-airline-themes`, `matchit`, `linediff`, `diffchar`, `spotdiff`

While editing a text file of a recognized type, nvim will sometimes "lose its mind" and stop syntax coloring at arbitrary points within the file. Sometimes it regains its senses on its own; sometime only after I hit return during `INPUT` mode; sometimes if I scroll down by hanging on the `<ENTER>` key while in `NORMAL` mode. Yet sometimes it never recovers and my only recourse is to quit nvim and re-launch. This happens rarely in "pure" text files, i.e. C, C++, Java, etc. but happens very, very often in "mixed" text files, i.e. HTML with JavaScript, PHP with HTML, etc. (I'm guessing that's "clue #1.") As the file grows larger, it happens more often. (I suppose that's "clue #2.") It happens in both Vim (nox) and Neovim. (Is that "clue #3?")

The weirdest thing is that when I say "*at arbitrary points*" I mean it: smack in the middle of a CSS style definition, it just stops syntax coloring. It's definitely not because of a block mismatch issue, i.e. {} or () or [], etc.

I have no idea where to start looking to diagnose this issue and I don't know what to do with these clues! Does anyone have any ideas?

(As an aside ... I use `vim-plug` for my plugins; for testing, can I disable a plugin without removing it?)